# E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate, how to resolve?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, git

I am facing below issue while installation time of git

```
sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

Note: I have uninstall and trying to install again.

Below is the output of **sudo apt update**

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: Please add output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease               

Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

@Pilot6 please check above

Comment: Your Ubuntu repos seem to be disabled. Enable everything except `proposed` in Software & Updates.